# How to find index positions of a substring using Python

Tags: python

Very new to Python here, and struggling. Any help is appreciated! Confession: this is obviously a request for help with homework, but my course ends tomorrow and the instructor takes too long to return a message, so I'm afraid if I wait I won't get this finished in time.

I'm using a learning module from Cornell University called introcs. It's documented here: http://cs1110.cs.cornell.edu/docs/index.html

I am trying to write a function that returns a tuple of all indexes of a substring within a string. I feel like I'm pretty close, but just not quite getting it. Here's my code:

```
import introcs 

def findall(text,sub):
    result = ()
    x = 0
    pos = introcs.find_str(text,sub,x)

    for i in range(len(text)):
        if introcs.find_str(text,sub,x) != -1:
            result = result + (introcs.find_str(text,sub,x), )
            x = x + 1 + introcs.find_str(text,sub,x)

    return result
```

On the call *findall('how now brown cow', 'ow')* I want it to return (1, 5, 10, 15) but instead it lops off the last result and returns (1, 5, 10) instead.

Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Comment: **I'm afraid if I wait I won't get this finished in time.** Whose fault is it that you waited until the last minute?

Comment: Your code relies heavily on a function `find_str()` from a module called `introcs`, which isn't a common module and you didn't provide the code. What does `find_str()` do exactly? Why even use it?

Comment: It looks like `introcs.find_str()` is the same as the built-in `str.find()` method.

Comment: Instead of making excuses for a reason to post homework, you can just post it, as long as you stick to the [rules for posting homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). That gets you answers quicker and avoids snarky comments.

Comment: @barmar - "looks like" but that's not the point of my question to OP, of course.

Comment: `x = x + 1 + introcs.find_str(text,sub,x)` this is suspicious - I don't get it. Anyway, you should be able to step through the code and see exactly what happens when you have found the second last match (and should be finding the last match on the next iteration).

Comment: You shouldn't use `for i in range(len(text)):`. You don't need to loop over every character in the input.

Comment: Like @Barmar said, you should use `for i in text` or `for i, char in enumerate(text)`

Comment: Have you tried printing `x` after each assignment? Probably not, or you'd seen that `x` takes the values 2, 8, and then 19. So that's your problem right there.

Comment: @walker No, he shouldn't be looping over the text at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop over all the characters in text. Just keep calling `introcs.find_str()` until it can't find the substring and returns `-1`.

Your calculation of the new value of `x` is wrong. It should just be 1 more than the index of the previous match.

Make `result` a list rather than a tuple so you can use `append()` to add to it. If you really need to return a tuple you can use `return tuple(result)` at the end to convert it.

```
def findall(text,sub):
    result = []
    x = 0
    while True:
        pos = introcs.find_str(text,sub,x)
        if pos == -1:
            break
        result.append(pos)
        x = pos + 1

    return result
```

Comment: Thank you, this was tremendously helpful! 

I had to tweak it a bit to fit within my instructors preferences (e.g., he hates break statements?), but you got me past the wall, so thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: IMHO he's wrong. Doing this without a break statement probably requires you to duplicate the code that sets `pos`.

Comment: Probably a difference of opinion lost on me at this stage of my learning. I was able to introduce a variable, "loop" set to True and then create an else statement that changed loop to False, and that seemed to satisfy all my test cases.

Comment: Ugh, that's even worse! Now I know why I see that style of coding in so many questions, professors like this.

Comment: Can you help me understand why your way is preferred?

Comment: Because it says clearly what it wants to do. When you want to stop looping, you `break`. Using a variable that serves no purpose other than to say whether you want to keep looping is redundant.

Comment: That makes sense to me! But my boss paid good money for me to take this class, and I've got to submit work the instructor will view favorably. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: lol OK. The important thing is the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use re to do it:

```py
import re

found = [i.start() for i in re.finditer(substring, string)]
```

Comment: fixed the code to include start index which is located in the match object

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows evidence of three separate attempts of keeping track of where you are in the string:

1. you loop over it with `i`
2. you put the position a `sub` was found at in `pos`
3. you compute an `x`

The question here is what do you want to happen in this case:

```
findall('abababa', 'aba')
```

Do you expect `[0, 4]` or `[0, 2, 4]` as a result? Assuming `find_str` works just like the standard `str.find()` and you want the `[0, 2, 4]` result, you can just start the next search at 1 position after the previously found position, and start searching at the start of the string. Also, instead of adding tuples together, why not build a list:

```
# this replaces your import, since we don't have access to it
class introcs:
    @staticmethod
    def find_str(text, sub, x):
        # assuming find_str is the same as str.find()
        return text.find(sub, x)


def findall(text,sub):
    result = []
    pos = -1

    while True:
        pos = introcs.find_str(text, sub, pos + 1)
        if pos == -1:
            break
        result.append(pos)

    return result


print(findall('abababa', 'aba'))
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 4]
```

If you only want to match each character once, this works instead:

```
def findall(text,sub):
    result = []
    pos = -len(sub)

    while True:
        pos = introcs.find_str(text, sub, pos + len(sub))
        if pos == -1:
            break
        result.append(pos)

    return result
```

Output:

```
[0, 4]
```